# Cryptic Family Reunion: I don't want to work

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

#### UPDATE!

The old clue for #2 was dirty pool...when I wrote it I remember thinking "is this fair...ah, it's fine" and moving on. It was not fine...replacement clue added.

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". **NOTE:** Unlike many previous puzzles in this genre, clues are NOT sorted alphabetically; however, lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Mom and me losing footing in place where we might be caught up? (7)
2. Nephew to remove foot from body an hour in advance (7) **(OLD...do not use)** Nephew to cancel form's final an hour in advance (7)
3. Dual transformation fixing initial vectors, derived sister (5)
4. Abuelita phones shut-in cousin (6)
5. Aunt Georgia pursuing criminal (5)
6. Uncle Bill uncovering flaw (5)
7. Daughter appears in Cuba Gooding's fifth, third and fourth Oscar bits (5)
8. Dad digests good French game (5)
9. Niece to turn erbium to gold within wood (6)
10. Uncle waving flag around, united on 1st of October (6)

Solver note: Most of these words are of foreign origin, though some have worked their way into English...be warned, and good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## ANSWER

They're all

> instruments. specifically, drums.

**Mom and me losing footing in place where we might be caught up? (7)**

> TIMPANI - "m" is me losing footing, and it's inside a place where we might be caught "in a pit" up (backwards)

**Nephew to remove foot from body an hour in advance (7)**

> BODHRAN - remove "y" from "body," HR is hour, and "an" is in "advance"

**Dual transformation fixing initial vectors, derived sister (5)**

> DAVUL - "Dual" transformed with the initial V in vectors fixed in the middle

**Abuelita phones shut-in cousin (6)**

> TAPHON - solved by @Stiv, hidden in "AbueliTA PHONes"

**Aunt Georgia pursuing criminal (5)**

> CONGA - con = criminal, GA = Georgia

**Uncle Bill uncovering flaw (5)**

> TABLA - tab = bill, la = uncovered letters in "flaw"

**Daughter appears in Cuba Gooding's fifth, third and fourth Oscar bits (5)**

> CUICA - CU = Cuba, Gooding's 5th is I, 3rd and 4th Oscar is CA

**Dad digests good French game (5)**

> BONGO - bon = good in French, and Go is a game

**Niece to turn erbium to gold within wood (6)**

> TIMBAU -> Erbium is ER, Gold is AU, and wood is "Timber" - remove "er" and add "au"

**Uncle waving flag around, united on 1st of October (6)**

> GUFALO - "flag", "u" for the first letter in united, and "O" for October, all waved around.

And a brief note on the theme:

> I don't want to work, I just want to bang on the drum all day

Comment: Well done :) The one beginning 'Abuelita' is rot13(GNCUBA), as it's 'shut in' the other words... It's from Thailand.

Comment: Theme is right, but 1, 9 and 10 were not what I had in mind. Suggest being more literal with the wordplay. I may not always follow "the rules", but I try to keep a toe on them :-) And thanks for getting the title!

Comment: Hah, it's okay that you don't follow the rules, I spent a long time yesterday googling "how to do a cryptic crossword" so I don't really know them anyway. I'll dig back in with a fresh brain on the ones I got wrong!

Comment: @JeremyDover made a couple of edits, did I get any closer?

Comment: One of the new answers is correct...but to the wrong clue! And now that I look at it, #2 is dirty pool...don't know how I missed that. Let me see if I can fix.

Comment: Okay - finally got the 7-letter ones I believe.

Comment: Yep! The wordplay in #2 is slightly different, since your interpretation would force h to be "in" ran. But you are very close!

Comment: I fixed all but the last one - someone else is gonna have to hop in, I have some thoughts that might help: rot13(synt zvtug or fpenzoyrq, be synt zvtug vaqvpngr gur raq bs n jbeq, be "onaare" zvtug or fpenzoyrq, gurer'f n qehz pnyyrq "eronan" ohg V pna'g svther bhg ubj gb trg gur erfg gb svg. cbffvoyl flabalzf sbe "havgrq" ner "bar" be "nyy"... gung'f nyy v unir.)

Comment: The last one is rarer than I thought. However, it does appear in rot13(uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Zrzoenabcubar).

Comment: LOL, V xarj vzzrqvngryl juvpu bar vg jnf, gur ahzore bs gvzrf V tbbtyrq qvssrerag crezhgngvbaf bs gubfr yrggref....

Comment: That's it! You got them all! Hope you enjoyed :-)